# Login button not working

Tags: php

I am new to web development and want to make a simple login form, although Not sure why my login button is not responding, the user is required to enter their email ans password. once the user enters a password the login button does not work.

```
 <?php
 session_start();



    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        include_once("php/config/database.php"); 
        $Email = strip_tags($_POST['Email']);
        $dbPassword = strip_tags($_POST['Password']);

        $Email = stripslashes($Email);
        $dbPassword = stripslashes($dbPassword);

        $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $Email);
        $dbPassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $dbPassword);

        $dbPassword = md5($dbPassword);

        $sql = ("SELECT * FROM 'Users' WHERE Email='$Email' LIMIT 1");
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $UserID = $row['UserID'];
        $dbpass_Password = $row['Password'];

        if($dbPassword == $dbpass_Password) {
            $_SESSION['Email'] = $Email;
            $_SESSION['UserID'] = $UserID;
            header("Location: account.php");
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "You didn't enter the correct details!";
        }

    } 


?>


        <html >
          <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>background</title>




                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
         <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

             <script src="js/index.js"></script>




          </head>

          <body>


            <div class="container demo-1">





              <div class="content">

                <div id="large-header" class="large-header">

              <form  action="index.php" method="POST>  
                  <div class="box">


              <h1 id="logintoregister">Login</h1>


          <div class="group show">      
              <input class="inputMaterial" type="text" name="FirstName" >
              <span class="highlight"></span>
              <span class="bar"></span>
              <label>First Name</label>
              </div>
            <div class="group show">      
              <input class="inputMaterial" type="text" name="Surname" >
              <span class="highlight"></span>
              <span class="bar"></span>
              <label>Surname</label>
              </div>


             <div class="group ">      
              <input class="inputMaterial" type="email" name="Email" >
              <span class="highlight"></span>
              <span class="bar"></span>
              <label>Email</label>
              </div>

            <div class="group">      
              <input class="inputMaterial" type="password" id="password" name="Password" >
              <span class="highlight"></span>
              <span class="bar"></span>
              <label>Password</label>
              </div>
            <div class="group show">      
              <input class="inputMaterial" type="password"  id="confirm_password" >
              <span class="highlight"></span>
              <span class="bar"></span>
              <label>Confirm Password</label>
              </div>


        <button id="buttonlogintoregister"  type = "submit" name="submit">Login</button>

          <p id="plogintoregister">By registering, You accept all terms and conditons </p>
          <p id="textchange" onclick="register()"> Sign Up</p>


                 </form> 




              <!-- Related demos -->




         <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

             <script src="js/index.js"></script>


        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Instead of `if($_POST['submit']) { ...` do `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { ...`

Comment: i tried it didn't work :(

Comment: In order to make it work you need to put everything inside the <form> tag and set attributes appropriately.-> http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 1):

Your html is broken:

```
      <form  action="index.php" method="POST" />  
                                              ^---
```

You self-closed the form tag, so EVERY input field on your page is  **OUTSIDE** of your form.

Plus note you have other logic bugs as well:

```
        if($Password == $dbpass_Password) {
              ^----
```

`$password` is an sql-escaped version of the user's PW. If that password naturally contains SQL metacharacters, the password will NOT compare as equal to what comes out of the database. Those escapes are stripped during the DB insert process, and you'll end up doing something like

```
 "Miles O\'Brien" == "Miles O'Brien"
```

and return a false mismatch.

Comment: Thanks i tried what you suggested, however still no luck. you can view the site for yourself if you like.